# React-js and react-spring => How to scale a div while scrolling

Tags: reactjs, scroll, scrollview, react-spring

I'm creating a website using reactjs and react-spring, and I have some Images that should **scaleUp or scaleDown** , when it's **inview** and the scaling UP/DOWN should stop when user stop scrolling and continue when user start scrolling again.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `react-use-gesture`'s `useScroll` to set value in spring?

Comment: I can't get react-spring to work with updating values while scrolling